# Fetch POSTs to localhost:3000 instead of localhost:8080

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, package.json

I have added "proxy": "http://localhost:8080" to my package.json file so that it will direct POST to 8080 but instead it says `AddBook.js:34 POST http://localhost:3000/api/book 404 (Not Found)`

Why is it sending it to 3000?

```
{
  "name": "appone-fe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my handlesubmit function, I have also tried just posting to "/book"

```
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        fetch("/api/book", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
            body: {
                ...state
            }
        }).then((a) => {
            alert(`status code ===> ${a.status}`)
        }).catch(error => alert(error))
    }
```

Comment: Your server runs on port 8080 ? Add your server-side code here too.

Comment: server runs on 8080 (built in scala). The React runs on 3000

Comment: Why are you sending the header (CORS) in the fetch request? This should be configured on the server-side.
Please show your server.js code as well